# How to make a copy of file in the same directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, cp, exec

This creates a file in the same directy as 'some.file.bak'.

```
find /home/ -ipath "*/temp/some.file" -type f  -exec cp {} {}.bak \;
```

How to make a copy in another name such as 'another.file' in the same directory as some.file  instead of 'some.file.bak'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `find /home/ -ipath "*/temp/some.file" -type f  -execdir cp {} another.file \;`

You just have to change `exec` to `execdir` from the other answer (sorry I cannot post it as a comment yet).

The `execdir` option states, according to `find`'s man page:

> -execdir command {} +
>
> > Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory  in which  you  started  find.

Comment: +1 I came up with a convoluted solution passing `{}` into a shell. This is an excellent answer: the solution and the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/ -ipath "*/temp/some.file" -type f  -exec cp {} another.file \;
```

Comment: i tried that earlier but cp copy another.file into the directory i run the script not the directory as some.file which i want.  Sorry, i should have elaborated same directory as some.file.